# search form using Zend Form with validators and inputFIlters

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-form, zend-framework2

Is there an example to see how one can implement a search form using Zend Forms in Zend Framework2. I needed a search form for every category and every category has different columns in the database which needs to be searched.

Let me say I have a Country category, under this there are many elements which can be searched like country name, states belonging to the county, language spoken in the country and so on.

So when a user types either a state or country or language I need to display all possible details. Is there something like a module already existing in Zend Framework2 or I should be implementing everything form scratch. In case if I need to do all from scratch, then what is the best way to approach this.

Im using Doctrine ORM to communicate with my DB. So in case if somebody has already worked on both of these then your suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You want to build your zend_form by the properties that are defined in your doctrine entity? You will have to

- use reflection to get all properties + data type + is-nullable?,
- iterate trough the properties (eventually implement a security mechanism which sorts out unwanted columns),
- build the zend_form while iterating, creating the corresponding zend_form_elements

After that you will have to create your Doctrine query according to the data you get from the form, dynamically setting WHERE statements for every property you get via POST.

**But that is not very practicable.**

In your situation i would build on a **full-text search engine** like lucene, elastic search or solr.

I don't know ZF2 (is it already in a state to use for productive environments? - when we analyzed it ~a year ago, we decided not to use it), but ZF1 has a class zend_search which allows to easily connect to a solr derivate.

We dont use it though cause its slow. Maybe there is a better implementation in ZF2 available now..

Comment: ZF2 is currently on on it's 2.0.5 release. It is ready for production. http://framework.zend.com/